# Not able to delete an entire row from a database mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I am trying to delete an entire row from the database it has table called "students" and it include four column when i run a delete query, it only delete two 
column data RegNo and Name. What can be the reason ?

```
 $names = [
       ['reg'=> $_POST['s1_id'], 'reg_set'=> $_POST['s1_id_set'] ,'name'=> $_POST['s1_name']],
       ['reg'=> $_POST['s2_id'], 'reg_set'=> $_POST['s2_id_set'],'name'=> $_POST['s2_name']], 
       ['reg'=> $_POST['s3_id'], 'reg_set'=> $_POST['s3_id_set'],'name'=> $_POST['s3_name']]
       ]; 




  $query_delete="delete from students where RegNo=:reg And ProjectID='$id'";

  $query_update="update students SET Name=:Name, RegNo=:reg_set WHERE 
  RegNo=:reg And ProjectID='$id'";

  foreach ( $names as $name)
  {
    try
   {

    if(!isset($name['reg_set']) && !isset($name['name']) )
    {

            $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query_delete );
            $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $name['name']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':reg', $name['reg']);

            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $msg = "Record deleted";

    }
    else
    {
      $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query_update );  
      $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $name['name']);
      $stmt->bindParam(':reg', $name['reg']);
      $stmt->bindParam(':reg_set', $name['reg_set']);
      $result = $stmt->execute();
      $msg = "Record updated";
    }
    //header("location:adminhome.php");
  }

  catch(PDOException $ex)
  {
      $msg = $ex -> getMessage();
  }
 }
```

Comment: what is the primary key of the table?

Comment: I'm no PDO expert, but why are you binding the name parameter to the delete query? You aren't using it in the query, and it stood out to me that the two columns that are being deleted are the parameters you set. I can't fathom it's making a difference, but still might be worth cleaning up.

Comment: @Ice76 primary key is RegNo

Comment: @TCooper, what can i do ?

Comment: delete this line: `$stmt->bindParam(':Name', $name['name']);` in the if portion of your if/else. Just for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic does not make sense. You check if name and reg are set, then, even if they are not, you try to use them in the DB query. From the results, it seems like you try to update that row with empty data, or null data, which is why they are empty and not being deleted.

Please display what `$msg` is, and rework your logic.

Comment: I think you're misreading his logic. If they're not set he uses the delete query with the :reg param, if they are set, he then makes use of them in the update query. I don't know why the :name param is in the delete query at all though.

Comment: @TCooper assuming that `$name['reg_set']` is not set, and that triggers the delete, he is then using parameters that he did not check for in that code block. If the primary key is `RegNo`, the that is all he should need for deleting a row.

Comment: yes, I made the assumption he knows that ['reg'] will always be set, or wishes to do nothing in cases where it isn't set. He's still using ['reg'] in the delete query, not ['reg_set'], and I previously commented saying he should remove the :name param from the delete query. Just don't see where he's "[checking] if name and reg are set, then, even if they are not, [trying] to use them in the DB query."

Comment: @TCooper well, OP seems to be MIA now. But from the image of the DB, seems like only the update statement was executed.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but either name or reg_set had to be set for the update query to run. They can’t both be empty and the update still run. Unless they’re set as empty strings of course... I’d actually bet that’s it